# Having problem with overlapping (Stacking) Label

Tags: java, swing, label, java-threads

Im trying to add a Score and Elapsed Time label (scoreAndTimer) to my already working snake game code. The problem is when I use scoreAndTimer.setText(); it stacks with previous text.

I tried to setText(); then setText(String); to clear previous one but it doesnt work also.

```
    private JLabel scoreAndTimer;
    private int sec, min;
    private Game game;


    public Frame() {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        game = new Game();

        frame.add(game);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setTitle("Snake");
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        scoreAndTimer = new JLabel();
        scoreAndTimer.setVerticalAlignment(SwingConstants.TOP);
        scoreAndTimer.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        frame.add(scoreAndTimer);
        timer();
    }

    private void timer(){
        while(game.isRunning()){
            scoreAndTimer.setText("SCORE: "+(game.getSnakeSize()-3)+"                                       Elapsed Time: "+timeFormatter());
            try{
                if(sec == 60){
                    sec = 0;
                    min++;
                }
                sec++;
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            }
            catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        if(!game.isRunning())
            scoreAndTimer.setText("Game Over");
    }

    private String timeFormatter(){
        if(sec < 10 && min < 10)
            return "0"+min+":0"+sec;
        else if(sec >= 10 && min < 10)
            return "0"+min+":"+sec;
        else if(sec < 10 && min >= 10)
            return min+"0:"+sec;
        else
            return min+":"+sec;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Frame();
    }
}
```

Program is working well but could'nt prevent overlap. There is no error. Im using totally 3 Threads in my program, im not sure if threads are making a problem about this. Code is a bit long thats why i dont share the rest for now, if needed i can share other parts also but i dont think the problem occurs at other classes.

Comment: Could you add a [mre] instead that reproduces the problem? I gave the example code you posted (after some modifications) a try, but wasn't able to see any overlap. I assume you were refering to mulitple `Score` and/or `GameOver` texts displayed at the same time.

Comment: Please provide us with a minimum reproducible example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. This should include all the 3 threads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`JFrame`, or more precisely it `contentpane` uses `BorderLayout` by default. 
 When you add components to a `JFrame`:

```
frame.add(game);
```

You implicitly add it to the `BorderLayout.CENTER` position, which is the default position. So `frame.add(game);` is equivalent to `frame.add(game, BorderLayout.CENTER);` 
The `BorderLayout.CENTER` position (as well as other `BorderLayout` positions) can hold **one** component.
The problem is that you add another component to the same `BorderLayout.CENTER` position by:

```
frame.add(scoreAndTimer);
```

The solution is to add `scoreAndTimer` to a different position:

```
 frame.add(scoreAndTimer, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
```

and have

```
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
```

at the end, **after** you have added all components.

Important side note: 
`timer()` as written is not going to work. Think of Swing Application as an application that runs on a single thread. When this thread is
busy with running the long while loop (like the one you have in `timer()`, it does not update the gui. The gui becomes unresponsive(freezes). 
Use [Swing timer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html).

Comment: Thanks for good advice, I changed ```frame.add(scoreAndTimer)``` with ```frame.add(scoreAndTimer,BorderLayout.NORTH)``` and it doesnt overlap now, but i have another problem now which seems easier. I have two different score board now.

Comment: I am glad it helped. Should you need more help post a new question and leave me a message. I'll do my best to help.

Comment: I created a new post about my new problem but Im not sure how to notice you, thats the link of new question ```https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57162757/why-my-code-creates-two-labesl-which-is-same```